# Django - data retrieved in postgres database not showing in application

Tags: django, postgresql

I had a database backup that i restored in postgres using COPY. The data is loaded correctly in database, a SELECT would show everything correctly. Yet in the connected app, the data is not being showed.

The application is a django application, in admin I can see the data count yet I can't see data records, as shown in the picture joint bellow.

[image]

We can see that I have 110 Question records yet the record entries are not accessible. Same thing with fetch and get.

It would be great if anyone can guide me through this, thanks.

Comment: You **should not** delete migration on your production server, this can cause greater risk.

Comment: I even cloned the project and redid the migrations, yet it didn't fix the issue @MoLoW